# How my node is sync with highest block number of block-chain in which block number transaction have done of some ether?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, rinkeby

I am new to Ethereum block-chain.One question in my mind. I connect geth node to test network with "--fast and --cache=2048" parameters.So my node is sync is after 8 hours.And I successfully deploy smart contract on test network(rinkeby). But one question in my mind.

1. **How does my node sync with the highest block number??**
2. **What is the format the time is displayed when I request for the sync status in Geth??**

It might be a silly question but here i want to understand this concept more deeply.

Please help to clear my above query.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Ismael my quesstion mean.I want to know how block number in which ethers transfer for transcation.How to sync with ethereum block-chain.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to how your node is syncing, It's done using the **DEVp2p** protocol. A brief is given [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27969/how-ethereum-nodes-sync-with-each-other)

> Currently, when a user submits a transaction that transaction is then
> sent to all their peers, which in turn send it to all their peers,
> etc. Within seconds every active full node in the Ethereum network
> should have the transaction hash at the very least. Miners receive
> this transaction, check for validity and other things (like orphaned
> transactions), then bundle it together with a bunch of other
> transactions they received into a block.

For time, this is taken from the yellow paper
According to the [Yellow Paper](https://ethereum.github.io/yellowpaper/paper.pdf)

> 4.3 **timestamp**: A scalar value equal to the reasonable output of **Unix's time()** at this block's inception; formally Hs
>
> 4.4 Hs is the timestamp of block H and must fulfill the relation: Hs > P(H)